# C++: Copying a stack of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, string, templates, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a program for an assignment that uses Linked-list-based stacks containing pointers to nodes containing string objects.
I want to print the stack `rod`, which utilizes `pop()`, which removes the head object each iteration until it is empty. So i need to find a way to backup `rod[]` before printing it.
I've tried pushing `rod[]`'s contents into `rodCopy[]` and then calling `rod[x] = rodCopy[x]`, which is supposed to restore rod[] to its original state but this doesn't appear to work because I start getting seg faults again.
The other issue is that it copies the stack backwards, since it stores the most recently stored object.
For example:

```
output:
rod[0] = "x", "xx", "xxx" //"x" is the top() object but "xxx" was the first
rodCopy[0] = "xxx", "xx", "x" // "x" is the first object, "xxx" is the top()
```

`TowerHanoi.h` file:

```
#ifndef TOWERHANOI_CAMERON_H
#define TOWERHANOI_CAMERON_H

#include "LStack.h"

namespace oreilly_A2 {

    class TowerHanoi {
    public:
        TowerHanoi();
        TowerHanoi(size_t numDiscs);

        LStack<std::string> get_Discs();

        void set_Discs(size_t disc);

        void print_Game();

        LStack<std::string> copyRod(int r);

        void setRod(LStack<std::string> r1, LStack<std::string> r2);


    private:

        LStack<std::string> rod[3];
        int discs, source, target;
    };
}
#endif
```

TowerHanoi.cpp `print_Game()`:

```
void TowerHanoi::print_Game() {
    string xString;

    LStack<string> rodCopy = rod[0];

    //string spacing;
    //int spaceInt= discs-1;
    for (size_t a=0; a<discs;a++) {
            xString = rod[0].pop();

            cout << xString; //print rod[0]
            if (!rod[1].empty()) { //is rod 2 empty?
                cout << "   ";
                xString = rod[1].pop();

                cout << xString; //print rod[1]
            }
            cout << endl;
    }

    string bottomRow; //print the bottom row after printing rods

    for (int c=0; c < (((discs*2)-1)+3);c++) {
        bottomRow.append("-");
    }
    string rodNum;
    for (int c=0; c < (discs/2);c++) {
        rodNum.append("-");
    }
    rodNum.append("rod 1");

    cout << bottomRow << endl;
    cout << rodNum << endl;


}
```

`LStack.template` file:

```
namespace oreilly_A2 {
template <typename Obj>
LStack<Obj>::LStack() {
    list = new LinkedList<Obj>();
    used=0;
}

template <typename Obj>
LStack<Obj>::~LStack() {
    delete list;
}
//push
template <typename Obj>
void LStack<Obj>::push(Obj head_in) {

    list->addToHead(head_in);
    used++;
}

//pop
template <typename Obj>
Obj LStack<Obj>::pop() {
    used--;
    return list->removeFromHead();

}
//top
template <typename Obj>
const Obj& LStack<Obj>::top() {
    return list->list_getHead();
}

//empty
template <typename Obj>
bool LStack<Obj>::empty() {
    if (list->getEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
//size
template <typename Obj>
int LStack<Obj>::size() const {
    return used;
}

}
```

LinkedList.template file `addToHead()` and `removeFromHead()`:

```
    template <typename Item>
void LinkedList<Item>::addToHead(Item entry) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new node<Item>(entry, NULL);
    }
    else {
        head = new node<Item>(entry, head);
    }


}

template <typename Item>
const Item LinkedList<Item>::removeFromHead() {
    node<Item>* tmp_ptr;
    tmp_ptr = head->link();
    std::string head_copy;
    head_copy = head->data(); //create a copy of head
    head = tmp_ptr;
    //delete tmp_ptr;
    //head->set_data(head->link()); //set head's data to the previous object
    return head_copy; //return head's original data
    //delete head_copy;
}
```

Node.template `set_data` and `set_link`:

```
    template <typename Object>
void node<Object>::set_data(const Object& new_data){
        std::string new_string;
        new_string = new_data;
        word = new_string;
}


template <typename Object>
void node<Object>::set_link(node<Object>* new_link){
        next= new_link; 

}
```

Comment: Does `LStack` have a copy constructor?

Comment: Looks like you need to define meaningful copy constructors for `LStack` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: I do not have copy constructors. How would one go about this? upon calling LStack() it calls `list = new LinkedList<Item>()` and when I call `node<Object>* obj = new node<Object>()` it initializes the `next` node to NULL

Comment: @CameronO'Reilly copy constructors should be explained in your introductory book.

Comment: I figured that given `addToHead()` allocates memory each time I push a new object into the `head` node that this creates a copy.

Comment: `LStack<string> rodCopy = rod[0];` that is a shallow copy which will reuse pointers. You need to define copy-constructors.